# htaccess redirection, urls with hashes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have urls like these:

```
http://domain.com/test/MzA5
http://domain.com/test/AtbC
http://domain.com/test/4gCA
```

How to make htaccess rule which will redirect all urls like http://domain.com/test/[hash here] to one page, for example http://domain.com/page.html

Comment: Do you want their browser redirected to show page.html in the address, or do you just want to serve content internally from page.html without changing the browser address?

Comment: you cannot redirect URLs with hashes.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey I think 'hash' is misused here to refer to the string value after /test/. There's no `#` in sight.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Redirect 301 /test/MzA5 /page.html
```

If you have a lot of those hashes, you can make a lot of 301 redirects:

```
Redirect 301 /test/MzA5 /page.html
Redirect 301 /test/AtbC /page.html
Redirect 301 /test/4gCA /page.html
```

or consider using a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) (which requires access to the server config, won't work in .htaccess file)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all URLs of the form /test/*/ to page.html, use the following rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test/[^/]+/? /page.html [R=301, L]
```